# How do I define a samba share so that every user can only see its own home?

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I would like to make every user's home directory from Debian machine to be available by its owner only (using Samba) but for now (with default Samba configuration) I can access other users `/home`s.

Here is the `[home]` config part :

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
public = no
read only = no
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
valid users = ashley joe %S
```

By logging on ashley's account from Windows 7 machine I can browse joe's home.
How should I configure this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change `valid users = ashley joe %S` to only `valid users = %S`. In your example, `ashley, joe and %S [the name of the share]` is always valid, so `ashley` and `joe` can reach all homes, any other (if there are) users should only see their own in the example you gave.

Comment: For others finding this via google %S is the name of the Current share's name, see http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/appc_01.html#appc-88529 for a list of all varaibles